# Which mysql join is better to use for this example

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, Table a and Table b with the following content

```
**Table a**  :  **Id    date**
            830     2005-09-21
            830     2006-01-04
            830     2006-03-15
            930     2006-05-03
            930     2006-06-21

**Table b**  :  **Id    new_date**
            830   2005-09-21
            830   2006-09-21
            930   2007-09-21
```

Desired output table should look like

```
            **id      date          new_date**
            830     2005-09-21    2005-09-21
            830     2006-01-04
            830     2006-03-15
            830                   2006-09-21
            930     2006-05-03
            930     2006-06-21
            930                   2007-09-21
```

I've tried left join and few other joins but the above output is not mentioned.
Which mysql join should i use? Thanks in advance

Comment: why not do a `UNION`? - or better yet, create a view that is a union of the two

Comment: and why do you have multiple id's with the same value?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try a left-join table B to A, alias the result as C, then a right-join of C back on B.

Something like this:

`Select * from 
(Select A.id, A.date, B.new_date from 
A left join B 
on A.id = B.id and A.date = B.new_date) C
right join B on C.id = B.id;`